# Python/Flask: ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, flask

Seemingly trivial problem that I can't figure out, despite going through documentation and the tutorial. Keeps on coughing up:

```
builtins.ValueError
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Whenever I try to render my template. Using PyCharm as the editor which doesn't warn about any problems.

**website.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    render_template('hello_world.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.debug = True

    app.run()
```

**hello_world.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello, Flask</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World and Flask!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should of course have been

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('hello_world.html')
```

Overlooked the 'return' when inserting render_template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refine your `hello_world` method as such:

`return render_template(...)`

The error you're seeing is sorta hinting at that. Flask is expecting a return value and instead nothing is seen.